# Rabbit Php-amqp lib client heartbeat is 0 but why server default 60 is not used?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, heartbeat, php-amqplib

I am testing heartbeat with long running consumers, on the rabbit documentation is stated that if the client sends 0 for heartbeat the greater value between client and server is used, but what I see is that is just disabled, but I don't have the configuration set in the rabbit config file so I expect the default to be 60 seconds. Connection is dropped as expected if is set the heartbeat on the client. Tried with rabbit 3.7 .

Am I understanding the documentation incorrectly ?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle check this its set to 0 you have to change to 60.